# How can i set domain name on my localhost?

Tags: networking

I run Apache on my Ubuntu system in local network.
there is more than 100 systems in the network so i want to set domain name on this system.
How can i do this?

Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a dns server somewhere within your domain, which any clients are pointed towards. This questions on [how to use bind in your lan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246009/how-can-i-use-bind9-to-use-my-own-custom-domain-in-my-lan) should help.

Failing that, there are a number of [questions regarding bind already](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=bind%20lan).

Answer (score 0):

If it is for just local use, you can just put the IP address entry into your hosts file.  You can make up any domain name you want for this.

On modern Windows, that is c:/Windows/drivers/etc/HOSTS

On linux, the file is /etc/hosts.

For the rest of the world, you will want a registered domain.  Then you can use your domain registrar's control panel to point it to your computer's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If for instance port defined in Apache is 8080, this can be done by assigning this port in the router to your machine. All requests to yourdomainname:8080 will go to your machine where Apache is installed. Another means is by using a DMZ defined in the router.