# How to resolve my localhost in LAN under Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, networking, apache2, dns, localhost

- I have a website that running on `localhost:8069` address.
- And I have network in network  each and every system is `Ubuntu 12.04 64bit`
- Actually what can I do is
- My website that running on `localhost:8069` is open in each and every system using `192.168.199.25:8069` link through
- But I dont want to gives any ones to my IP i am just gives you `helpdesk` then what can i do
- when any one who is in the network is hit on the `helpdesk:8069` just open my website
- please help me,i have so many things are search but i don't understand what can i do.

Answer (score 2):

`helpdesk` would be a DNS name in this case. In order for other users on your network to resolve that DNS name to your IP, there are several choices:

### Using /etc/hosts

If you have few users on your network, and your IP never changes, you can add the following line to each machine's /etc/hosts file:

```
 192.168.199.25 helpdesk
```

### Using a DNS server

If you are running a local DNS server, you could add an entry there to resolve the `helpdesk` name to your IP. For explanations on how to do that, have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246009/how-can-i-use-bind9-to-use-my-own-custom-domain-in-my-lan?rq=1).